# C# Error CS0738 when class inherits from interface and with type that inherits from interfce type method

Tags: c#, class, interface

I got CS0738 when class impelments an interface, and interface has a method, with return type interface.

And in class return type is a struct that implements return type interface.

Simply, this code shows the problem:

```cs
public interface IGame
{
    IPlayer WhoWin();
}

public interface IPlayer
{
    int ID { get; }
}
```

And in class:

```cs
public class MyGame : IGame
{
    // ERROR CS0738
    public MyPlayer WhoWin()
    {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
}

public class MyPlayer : IPlayer
{
    public int ID 
    {
        get
        {
            return ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color);
        }
    }
    public Color Color;
}
```

What should I do? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: A class doesn't **inherit** an interface - it **implements** it ..... inheritance only works between classes themselves

Comment: Make the return type an object. : public object WhoWin()

Comment: @marc_s I have edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `IGame` generic interface and apply `where T : IPlayer` constraint

```cs
public interface IGame<out T> where T : IPlayer
{
    T WhoWin();
}
```

Then implement it like

```cs
public class MyGame : IGame<MyPlayer>
{
    public MyPlayer WhoWin()
    {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type of `WhoWin` from `MyPlayer` to `IPlayer` in your `MyGame` class then it should work.

```
public class MyGame : IGame
{
    // CHANGE THIS TO IPlayer like here:
    public IPlayer WhoWin()
    {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
}

public class MyPlayer : IPlayer
{
    public int ID 
    {
        get
        {
            return ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color);
        }
    }
    public Color Color;
}
```